# Highcharts Server not loading infile correctly

Tags: highcharts

I am having difficulty having the export feature to work on my server. I have tried searching and there is not much I can get specifically. I have tried both features and the same error shows up each time. This is the error I am getting

> > ./phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile test.js -outfile chart.png

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $

ERROR: the options variable was not available, contains the infile an syntax error? see ->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

contents of test.js are :

> > {
> >             xAxis: {
> >                     categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
> >             },
> >             series: [{
> >                     data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
> >             }]
> >     };

I have tried putting it in JSON format but it doesn't seem to be working...

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same error...

Make sure you have 3 important files in the same folder as `highcharts-convert.js`

1. `highcharts.js` -or- `highstock.js`
2. `highcharts-more.js`
3. `jquery.js`

Then, update the file names at the top of `highcharts-convert.js` to match these file names and save it.

```
var config = {
        /* define locations of mandatory javascript files */
        HIGHCHARTS: 'highcharts.js',
        HIGHCHARTS_MORE: 'highcharts-more.js',
        JQUERY: 'jquery.js',
        TIMEOUT: 2000 /* 2 seconds timout for loading images */
    },
```

Now you should have no more errors (or at least a different one, ha)

Comment: And let me know if you encounter other errors because I just went through the whole process of setting this up so I can probably help with those too

Comment: I have all the 3 files in place. But it still wont work for me

Answer (score 3):

When I downloaded `highcharts-convert.js` it had a tiny typo in the config: instead of `jquery-1.9.1.min.js` it said `jquery.1.9.1.min.js` (note the `.` instead of a `-`)

Took me an hour of digging and experimenting to figure it out... Hope this can save others some time.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar error. When I had downloaded the HighCharts package, I ended up with highcharts-convert.js containing:

```
HIGHCHARTS: 'highstock.js'
```

rather than

```
HIGHCHARTS: 'highcharts.js'
```

Once I changed that filename, the chart was generated without issue.

Comment: I dont see that anymore at inthe current version of highcharts-convert.js https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-export-server there doesnt seem be any HIGHCHARTS line in the JS code anymore did it change?

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the jquery filename within highcharts-convert.js. The part that says JQUERY: 'jquery.1.9.1.min.js', should be jquery-1.9.1.min.js. Note the '-' instead of '.'.

Also if you are getting a bunch of errors other than ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $ make sure you comment out the file dependencies that you don't need in the top of highcharts-convert.js.

That was quite frustrating to figure out...

Comment: In the current version of highcharts-convert.js https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-export-server there doesnt seem be any JQUERY or HIGH charts line in the JS code anymore did it change?

Answer (score 0):

In highcharts-convert.js you have to define paths for:

- Highcharts library
- jQuery library

Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. I was invoking the command from shell_exec within PHP and Apache Web Server. The user that executed the command (www-data or apache) doesn't have read permissions on jquery.min.js so the execution fails (by the way apache was killed by phantomjs) and I had ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $ because jquery weren't included at all. Hope this helps